# How to update the output of activation function after each batch ends, using Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

If I want after each batch ends to update the output activation of a specific layer, How can I do that in Keras?

For example, the output shape of a specific layer= [9,1500], where 9 is the batch size and 1500 is the output features. How can I update this output after each batch ends ?

This is my model architecture:

```
from keras.models import Sequential,Model  
from keras.layers import Input,Embedding,Conv1D,Multiply,Activation,MaxPooling1D,Dense,Flatten  

vocab_size=467   
outPut_dimention=8  
sequence_length=429278   
main_input = Input(shape=(sequence_length,), name='main_input')  
embedding_layer=Embedding(vocab_size+1,outPut_dimention,input_length=sequence_length)(main_input)  
one_D_conv_layer1=Conv1D(128,32,strides=32 , activation='sigmoid' )(embedding_layer)  
one_D_conv_layer2=Conv1D(128,32,strides=32, name="conv1d")(embedding_layer)  
merge=Multiply()([one_D_conv_layer1,one_D_conv_layer2])  
max_pooling=MaxPooling1D(pool_size=400)(merge)  
flat_layer=Flatten()(max_pooling)  
fully_connected=Dense(128)(flat_layer)  
main_output=Dense(9, activation='softmax')(fully_connected)  
model=Model(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[main_output])  

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer="Nadam",
              metrics=['accuracy'])  

history1=model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    use_multiprocessing=True,
                    workers=6,
                    epochs=1,callbacks=[myCallBack])
```

What I want to do is that during the training process, I want to update the out put of the fully_connected layer at the end of each batch. For example, if the output of the fully_connected layer is a numpy array of shape (?, 128), where ? is the batch size, then I want to update that numpy array at the end of each batch.

Comment: pls provide a concrete example (with code) of what you have, and what you want to achieve

Comment: Is it clear now for what I want to achieve?

Comment: not sure, but I removed my downvote...

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "update the output".

Comment: I want to modify the output ( the numpy array) of a specific layer during the training process by the end of each batch. An output of a specific layer after training on a batch could be a numpy array of shape (batch size, n_features) . Is it clear now @MatiasValdenegro ?

Comment: Not really, because what would that actually do? Layer outputs depend on their inputs, there is no point in "modifying" the output of a layer.

Comment: I'm trying to implement a new regularization technique called DeCov regularization, which is introduced by (Cogswell et al. 2016). This regularization reduces the correlation between the activation nodes for a given layer by modifying the output of a layer.   @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: I've read that paper and it just proposed a new loss term (the DeCov loss), it doesn't say that you manually have to modify the activations, this happens automatically with the loss term on the activations.

Comment: Yea, but in order to apply the loss formula I need to have an access to a layer output, so that I can apply the formula of the DeCov loss, right? I need to have an access to the numpy array of a given layer by the end of each batch: (batch_size,n_nodes). Then calculate the DeCov loss from this numpy array, and then add it to the main loss (cross entropy). @MatiasValdenegro

Comment: Can you please go over my solution and tell me if it's right. @MatiasValdenegro

Answer (score 0):

I found on Keras official website [link](https://keras.io/regularizers/) a way to define your costume regularization under the section "Developing new regularizers". Since I need to have an access to layer output (batch_size,n_nodes), then I need to define a custom activity_regularizer.

```
from keras import backend as K

class Regularizer(object):
    """Regularizer base class.
    """

    def __call__(self, x):
        return 0.

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        return cls(**config)



class DeCovRegularizer(Regularizer):

#     def set_layer(self, layer):
#         self.layer = layer

    def __call__(self, x):
#         print(x.shape)
        # x will be the output of the layer: (batch_size,n_nodes)
        # means=[u1,u2,u3,u4,....] : where u1 is the (sum of node1 over the batch size)/batch_size
        means=(K.sum(x,axis=0)/batch_size)  #axis=0 to sum over the column not the rows 
        sub_mean=x-means # we subtract the mean from the nodes; for Example, node1-u1, node2-u2 ...... 
        node_numbers=x.shape[1] # in our example it will be 128
        # Constructing the C matrix; however it will be 1Dim=[c1_2,c1_3....c1_n,c2_1,c2_3......,c2_d.......]
        C=K.variable(np.array([0])) # initialize C with 0 --> C=[0]

        for i in range (0,node_numbers):
            for j in range(0,node_numbers):
                if(i !=j): 
                    C_i_j=K.sum(sub_mean[:,i]*sub_mean[:,j],keepdims=True)
                    C=K.concatenate([C, C_i_j], axis=-1)

        DecovLoss=K.sum(C*C)/0.5
        return DecovLoss

#     def get_config(self):
#         return {"name": self.__class__.__name__,
#             "p": self.l1}
```

in my model I added the Decov loss  as following :

```
fully_connected=Dense(128,activity_regularizer=DeCovRegularizer())(flat_layer)
```

Just to make sure, during the training process the returned value by the **call** function will be added to the main loss (cross entropy), right? so that the Decov loss will be added automatically to the cross entropy loss, is that right? Am I implementing the DeCov loss correctly ?